# How to launch a Grade SonarQube analysis with help of the Jenkins SonarQube plugin

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I have installed Sonarqube plugin in Jenkins and configurations are done for SonarQube and sonar-runner in Manage Jenkins->configure System.
I want to trigger analysis for Gradle project. I would like to know the steps to be followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jenkins SonarQube plugin only allows to easily launch some SonarQube analysis with help of SonarRunner or Maven. If you want to launch a SonarQube analysis with help of the Gradle SonarQube plugin (see [the docs](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/gradle.html)) you must manually configure your Jenkins job to execute 'gradle sonarqube'. Simple example for SonarQube with Gradle is provided [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-gradle).

Comment: By the way, this question slightly relates to http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-217

Comment: While this is the only answer for now, it is disappointing.  This means that all projects which wish to use SonarQube with Gradle need to have URLs, credentials and passwords in their build.gradle files.

With Maven, these details could be configured per Jenkins instance.  That means there's a greater maintenance (and security) overhead by using Gradle.

I hope that in time, a plugin for Jenkins and Gradle with similar functionality to Jenkins/Maven will be developed by SonarQube.

Comment: I agree the gradle integration is a bit disappointing. Also, I have tried to use the sonar scanner instead of the plugin by using a `sonar-project.properties` and I got difficulties to retrieve the same params from the gradle plugins. Would be nice to be able to print them out or to add more documentations.

Comment: @Freddy-SonarSourceTeam link is broken